# Angular DI Injection token with existing providers

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular2-aot

There is a list of services that implements some **CommonInterface**

```
const services = [Service_1, Service_2, Service_3];
```

i define these services as a providers in a module

```
providers: [...services],
```

1) i want to use these services in my components and have DI on each of them
2) i want to use these services as an array and have DI on all of them

1 is working for me, cause i created providers, for 2 - i created an injection token

```
export const MY_SERVICES = new InjectionToken<CommonInterface>('my.services');
```

and in providers section of module i define

```
    providers: [
       ...services,
     {
          provide: MY_SERVICES ,
          useExisting: Service_1,
          multi: true
        },
     {
          provide: MY_SERVICES ,
          useExisting: Service_2,
          multi: true
        },
     {
          provide: MY_SERVICES ,
          useExisting: Service_3,
          multi: true
        },
]
```

This works fine for me but the question is: why i can`t define my injection token this way:

```
 const toInjectionToken = clazz => ({
      provide: MY_SERVICES,
      useExisting: clazz,
      multi: true
    });
providers: [ ...myServices,  ...myServices.map(toInjectionToken)]
```

This works fine with JIT compiler, but for AOT its an error:
**- Invalid provider for the NgModule ,  only instances of Provider and Type are allowed**

How can i achieve the same with a less verbose module definition and AOT ?

added DEMO:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mjvdbl

Comment: Can you create StackBlitz?

Comment: yup, added, - this works fine, i assume stackblitz use JIT

Comment: Yes, I know. Just wanted to see and export to my local for AOT building.

Comment: I updated my answer. PLease, take a look at that